# Animating the labels on input focus with CSS and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a few input fields and I want their labels to scale down and slide at the top on focus. I have managed to achieve this with CSS and JavaScript but it only animates the first label on the page.

The code JS below uses "querySelector" to target the labels. I've also tried using "getElementsByClassName" and "querySelectorAll". What that does is animate all the labels on the page when I focus on just one input field.

I'd like to only animate the label attached to input. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

```js
document.addEventListener("change", function(event) {

  if (event.target && event.target.matches(".js_form-input")) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var inputField = event.target;
    var inputLabels = document.querySelector(".label-span");

    if (inputField.value) {
      inputLabels.style.top = "-1.5rem";
    } else {
      inputLabels.style.top = "0rem";
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.input {
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: solid 1px grey;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  color: $c_pop;
  padding-bottom: 0.7rem;
}

.input-label {
  position: relative;
}

.label-span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 1rem;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.input-label {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}

.input:focus+.label-span {
  top: -1.5rem;
  left: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 0.7rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-container">
  <label class="input-label" for="#">
    <input class="input js_form-input" type="text">
    <span class="label-span">First Name</span>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="input-container">
  <label class="input-label" for="#">
    <input class="input js_form-input" type="text">
    <span class="label-span">Surname</span>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="input-container">
  <label class="input-label" for="#">
    <input class="input js_form-input" type="text">
    <span class="label-span">Email</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

I've also tried this JS method:

```
var inputField = event.target;
        var inputLabels = document.querySelectorAll(".label-span");
    
         [].slice.call(inputLabels).forEach(function(label){
          if (inputField.value) {
            label.style.top = "-1.5rem";
           } else {
            label.style.top = "0rem";
           }
       });
```

Comment: You are doing perfect but in css, you are not properly defining class names. Use dot (.) with all class names in css and I don't think, Any javascript is required for this. Remove your javascript code. I hope, It will solve your problem.

Comment: That was a typo in editing the question on here. I've corrected it. The issue still persists.

Comment: @KumarGaurav javascript is required to keep the label up when any input looses focus and its value is not an empty string.

Comment: @Yousaf Not certainly, you can achieve the same result without JS. you can see my second approach. Let me know, if I missed any corner case.

Comment: @KumarGaurav Using `required` attribute along with `:valid` selector will not work if, for example, you have a password input field where valid password contains minimum of 8 characters. In this case, if you specify `minlength="8"` on the `input` element, then if user has typed, for example, 5 characters, label will move down when input looses focus.

Comment: @Yousaf Yeah, you are right. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSS is sufficient to get the affect you are after, just remove the javascript. The only problem that I fixed is adding `pointer-events: none;` to the `.label-span` elements as they were blocking focus when clicking on them.

Edited to include a check on blur for whether the input is empty or not and maintain the label position if it is full.

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.js_form-input');

inputs.forEach(input => {
    input.addEventListener('blur', (event) => {
    if (event.target.value.length) {
        event.target.classList.add("full");
    } else {
        event.target.classList.remove("full");
    }
});
})
```

```css
#container {
  padding: 2rem 0;
}

.input {
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: solid 1px grey;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  color: $c_pop;
  padding-bottom: 0.7rem;
}

.input-label {
  position: relative;
}

.label-span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 1rem;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.input-label {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}

.input:focus+.label-span, .input.full+.label-span {
  top: -1.5rem;
  left: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 0.7rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="input-container">
    <label class="input-label" for="#">
      <input class="input js_form-input" type="text">
      <span class="label-span">First Name</span>
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="input-container">
    <label class="input-label" for="#">
      <input class="input js_form-input" type="text">
      <span class="label-span">Surname</span>
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="input-container">
    <label class="input-label" for="#">
      <input class="input js_form-input" type="text">
      <span class="label-span">Email</span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, however it's not the perfect solution. If you focus on the input, the label does animate. But when you type something into the input and focus out, the label animates back to where it was and covers the value of the input field.

Comment: Too true @rockymalpo, edited my answer to include value check.

Answer (score 1):

**I hope, This will solve your problem.**

```js
var myform = document.querySelectorAll(".input-label");

        Array.from(myform).map(x => {
            x.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
                var el = e.target.parentNode.children[1];
                if (e.target.value !== "") {
                    el.style.top = "-1.5rem";
                } else {
                    el.style.top = "0rem";
                }
            });
        });
```

```css
* {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }

        .input-container {
            padding: 20px;
        }

        .input {
            width: 100%;
            border: 0;
            border-bottom: solid 1px grey;
            padding-left: 1rem;
            margin-bottom: 2rem;
            color: #000;
            padding-bottom: 0.7rem;
        }

        .input-label {
            position: relative;
        }

        .label-span {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 1rem;
            transition: all 0.2s;
        }

        .input-label {
            font-size: 0.9rem;
        }

        .input:focus+.label-span {
            top: -1.5rem;
            left: 0.5rem;
            font-size: 0.7rem;
        }
```

```html
<div class="input-container">
            <label class="input-label" for="#">
                <input class="input js_form-input" type="text" />
                <span class="label-span">First Name</span>
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="input-container">
            <label class="input-label" for="#">
                <input class="input js_form-input" type="text" />
                <span class="label-span">Surname</span>
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="input-container">
            <label class="input-label" for="#">
                <input class="input js_form-input" type="text" />
                <span class="label-span">Email</span>
            </label>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Another trick to achieve same result without Javascript.**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.input-container {
  padding: 20px;
}
.input {
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: solid 1px grey;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  color: #000;
  padding-bottom: 0.7rem;
}

.input-label {
  position: relative;
}

.label-span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 1rem;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.input-label {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}

.input:focus + .label-span,
.input:valid + .label-span {
  top: -1.5rem;
  left: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="input-container">
      <label class="input-label" for="#">
        <input class="input js_form-input" type="text" required />
        <span class="label-span">First Name</span>
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="input-container">
      <label class="input-label" for="#">
        <input class="input js_form-input" type="text" required/>
        <span class="label-span">Surname</span>
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="input-container">
      <label class="input-label" for="#">
        <input class="input js_form-input" type="text" required/>
        <span class="label-span">Email</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I agree that this is a neat CSS only solution, but it confuses validation functionality with a display concern that is not validation related. (The label should stay pushed up if there is text in the field regardless of whether that text is valid for the specific field or not.)